# Dynamically add checkboxlist into placeholder and get the checked value of the checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am creating an admin Page, in which checkboxlist(User list from DB)is to be created dynamically and its the checked users value is retrieved.

There are different types of users, so it is distinguised groupwise.

Now first a panel is defined, the checkboxlist is created dynamically and placed inside the panel, then the panel is placed inside a Placeholder.

What Iam doing here is placing the checkboxlist inside the panel, then the panel inside the placeholder. So the values of the Checkboxlist is not retrieved, due to the panel it doesnt get the checkboxlist and it doesn't loop through the Checkboxlist.

What I have done is.

```
    private void AddControl(string pUserGrp, int pUserGrp_Id, int pName)
    {           
        CheckBoxList chkList = new CheckBoxList();
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        User us = new User();
        us.OrderBy = "Order By User_Name";
        us.WhereClause = "Where UserRole_Id = " + pUserGrp_Id ;
        chkList.ID = "ChkUser" + pName ;
        chkList.AutoPostBack = true;
        chkList.Attributes.Add("onClick", "getVal(ChkUser" + pName + ");");
        chkList.RepeatColumns = 6;
        chkList.DataSource = us.GetUserDS();
        chkList.DataTextField = "User_Name";
        chkList.DataValueField = "User_Id";                        
        chkList.DataBind();
        chkList.Attributes.Add("onClick", "getVal(this);");

        Panel pUser = new Panel();

        if (pUserGrp != "")   
        {
            pUser.GroupingText = pUserGrp ;
            chk.Text = pUserGrp;            
        }
        else 
        {
            pUser.GroupingText = "Non Assigned Group";
            chk.Text = "Non Assigned group";
        }
        pUser.Controls.Add(chk);
        pUser.Controls.Add(chkList);
        Place.Controls.Add(pUser);                          
   }

    private void setChecked(int pPageGroupId)
    {
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        PageMaster obj = new PageMaster();
        obj.WhereClause = " Where PageGroup_Id = " + pPageGroupId;
        arr = obj.GetPageGroupUserRights(null);

        CheckBoxList chkList = (CheckBoxList)Place.FindControl("ChkUser");

        if (chkList != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < chkList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (arr.Count > 0)
                {
                    int ii = 0;
                    while (ii < arr.Count)
                    {
                        PageMaster oCand = (PageMaster)arr[ii];

                        if (oCand.User_Name == chkList.Items[i].Text)
                        {
                            if (!chkList.Items[i].Selected)
                            {
                                chkList.Items[i].Selected = true;
                            }
                        }
                        ii++;
                        oCand = null;                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetListCheckBoxText()
    {
        StringBuilder sbtext = new StringBuilder();            
        foreach (Control c in Place.Controls)
        {             
            if (c.GetType().Name == "CheckBoxList")
            {
                CheckBoxList cbx1 = (CheckBoxList)c;

                foreach (ListItem li in cbx1.Items)
                {
                    if (li.Selected == true)
                    {
                        sbtext.Append(",");
                        sbtext.Append(li.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sbtext.Append(li.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return sbtext.ToString();        }
```

It doesnt get through the Checkboxlist control in the setChecked(), also doesnt loop through the GetListCheckBoxTest().

Anyone can plz help me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to find a control (in `setChecked`) without setting the `Name` property. You are using this:

```
CheckBoxList chkList = (CheckBoxList)Place.FindControl("ChkUser");
```

But where is this in `AddControl`?

```
chkList.Name = "ChkUser";
```

And in `GetListCheckBoxText` instead of...

```
if (c.GetType().Name == "CheckBoxList")
```

...use this:

```
if (c.GetType()== typeof(CheckBoxList))
```

Comment: Really tahnx a lot for replying.

I have tried this already, but its giving error.

And the I have given 

<p>
chkList.ID = "ChkUser";

and I couldn't get .Name for chkList, its suggesting NamingContainer.

Is there any other way to do it.

PLz help me.